# Adding lines to parenthesis in Xcode as others code editors

Tags: swift, xcode, formatting, xcode13

how can I add lines to my code on Xcode as other code editors like the image below?

[image]

Comment: As in `Xcode > Preferences > Text Editing > Display > Show: ✅ Line Numbers`? It's not entirely clear what you're asking here.

Comment: OP probably means the vertical lines that appear on each indention level (very faint in the blurry image).

Comment: @DarkDust Oh wow, good catch — I didn't even consciously notice those. That's not something that Xcode supports.

Comment: `Editor/Invisible` is the closest visual "effect" you can have. The "Ribbon" (in Preferences) can also be a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I add lines to my code on Xcode as other code editors like the image below?

You can't, because Xcode doesn't render code that way. However, those vertical lines are often used to indicate which lines will be collapsed or folded, and Xcode *does* support code folding:

[image: sample code with folding bars]

The vertical gray bars next just to the right of the line numbers are Xcode's way of showing how code is nested. If you place the cursor over one of those bars, Xcode highlights the beginning and ending braces. Clicking on a bar will fold the corresponding block down to a single line with `...` between the braces. This is similar to what the vertical indentation lines do in some other editors.